# Strange Behaviour With Foreach Loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am experiencing some strange behaviour with the following foreach loop.
I am running it on PHP 5.3.0.

```
print_r($this->form_spec['fields']);
foreach($this->form_spec['fields'] as $f=>$field) {
     print_r($this->form_spec['fields']);                      
}
```

The first print_r prints the following (note: I've excluded a bunch of keys to make my point clearer):

```
Array
(      
    [0] => Array
    (
       [field_name] => d_first_name
    )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => d_last_name
        )
)
```

The second `print_r` prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => d_first_name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => d_first_name
        )
)
```

$this->form_spec['fields'] already has it's values before it reaches the for each loop. The first print_r shows the correct values.
Then the second print_r shows that the values have changed. There is no other code between these.

Could it be a bug in 5.3.0?

The only way I could get round the problem was by using a for loop instead, but the Foreach SHOULD work, it always has done before. Can anybody enlighten me?

[EDIT] Just to clarify, the bug is that the contents of $this->form_spec['fields'] changes not the fact that I can't print properly.

Comment: To format code on stackoverflow, select it and press `Ctrl`+`K`.

Comment: So what is your problem?
You `print_r` the same var twice and have the same result twice....

Comment: the second print_r throws d_first_name twice it seems, or isn't that the issue

Comment: Correct, the values inside $this->form_spec['fields'] change, and they shouldn't.

Comment: It's not strange, it's a foreach-context...

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. I have edited again my question.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing `$this->form_spec['fields']` instead of the result of the iteration `$field`.

**EDIT**

Now that I can see what you mean. It looks like you are changing the contents of the object while iterating over it somewhere in your loop. Could you please post the relevant code?

I'm 99% sure there is more code which is touched while iterating which changes what you have.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I have got rid of everything in the foreach loop. What you see there is the whole foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this:-

```
print_r($this->form_spec['fields']);
foreach($this->form_spec['fields'] as $f=>$field) {
     print_r($field);                      
}
```

I have run this test on your code:-

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $form_spec['fields'][] = array('field_name' => 'field_' . $i);
}
print_r($form_spec['fields']);
foreach($form_spec['fields'] as $f => $field) {
    print_r($form_spec['fields']);
}
```

(PHP_VERSION = 5.3.0)

and got the output I expected, so you must be altering that array somewhere. You need to check your code very carefully.

Output:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => field_0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => field_1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => field_2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => field_3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => field_4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => field_5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => field_6
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => field_7
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => field_8
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [field_name] => field_9
        )

)
```

Repeated 10 times.

Comment: Hi, the point is, the values inside $this->form_spec['fields'] change, and they shouldn't.

Comment: @AntonyDAndrea Then please make that clearer in the question.

Comment: +1, it's not clear and the code shows absolutely no assignment of the form_spec variables.

Comment: Thanks for that! I understand. But if I am changing the array somehow somewhere else, why doesn't it overwrite when I do the for loop? Also, it works if I do $f=>&$field instead inside the foreach loop.

Comment: So you *are* changing it in the loop?

Comment: No I am not, I said if was I was outside the loop, it why doesn't if change if I do a for loop. Also, the print_r shows the same data if I did $f=>&$field, i.e. it doesn't change. But it shouldn't change for any of the scenarios!

Comment: Well the solution was using a for loop instead. Whatever is the cause of this problem is still unknown, but, it so weird, its impossible to explain! The array is not being changed elsewhere, it it was, using a for loop wouldn't make a difference

Comment: @AntonyDAndrea Whilst I appreciate the rep, it may be in your interest not to accept this answer as it didn't solve your problem. Despite the comments posted by some people you are not obligated to accept answers. Somebody may come along and post a solution to your problem if there is no accepted answer.